# Read data from doc, xls files with PHP

Tags: php, excel, ms-word, xls

I wonder is it possible to read data from doc and xls files and put the 
readed content into image files(create page samples of the document). For example
I have documents that I want my customers to buy. So I need automatically to create little images like samples of mine documents.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

For reading from xls files I can really recommend [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) whic is a really simple, but powerful tool:) As for doc I unfortunatly got no good recommandation for you. But I'm sure there's something good out there.

Edit: Found a quick little solution to reading doc-files with one line of code using terminal commands, might not cover all your needs, but thought it was worth a mention. Note that this is only for doc, not docx. [Read doc from PHP](http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php)

Comment: While PHPExcel can read the xls files, it can't generate an image of that file directly. However, it can generate an HTML output from the loaded file, and that could then be "grabbed" as an image file by a screengrabber.

Comment: Might have been me misunderstanding the question, if it's just a thumbnail of the documents I guess there's no point reading out the data at all. Just find some software that can create open the files and create a screenshot. Thought he needed the read out the data from this files as the post said in which case PHPExcel is brilliant. You also got software like ImageMagick which might be helpful, atleast it's great for generating images from PDF documents using commandline, but that will most likely not work for doc and xls.

Comment: Actually I need to make screenshot of the file. I guess Im thinking in hard way... Does ImageMagic make screenshots out of word or excel files ?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I don't think ImageMagick has support for those formats. You'll probarbly need some software that can open a file using the GUI, then make a screenshot. Software like that exists, a former co-worker of mine did something similar for a project. But I don't know the details about how it was done so can't really recommend anything spesific

Comment: Maybe it is possible to do twice:

1. Convert doc to pdf with http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/02/06/convert-doc-to-pdf-in-php/
2. And then pdf convert(make screenshot) to image with ImageMagick

Answer (score 0):

Although this would be very cool and very handy, unfortunately not. There might be a way to do it with the Google Docs API, but I doubt it :-(

James

Comment: But gmail opens doc files pretty well. Probably there are any chances.

Comment: Does anyone know if there are .doc processing functions in the API?

Answer (score 0):

Providing your are on Linux you can use Antiword to get just the text of a Word 2000 doc. To get the text content of a Word 2007 document you need to unzip it and read the XML contained with in. Like this http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/reading_the_clean_text_from_docx_odt.php

To get a screenshot of the actual word doc with all its formatting however would probably require running a version of Word on the server and screenshotting it like Litmus does with browsers.